# How to pass model values from previous page to new page post method using ajax?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Home.cshtml

```
  @model Models.MyData 
    @using (Html.BeginForm("AddData", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))

    {
    }
```

HomeController.cs

```
 [HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult> AddData(MyData mydata)
        {

            return View("AddDetails", mydata);
}
```

I'm getting values here at `mydata` now I want to redirect to next page with same model values for that on pageload of new redirected page i write ajax call but it pass null model.

AddDetails.cshtml

```
@model Models.MyData 

<script>

var someRootPath = "@Url.Content("~")";

        $.ajax({
            url: someRootPath + 'Home/Process',
            data: $('#AddData').serialize(),


            type: "POST",            
        });
    }
  </script>
```

HomeController.cs

```
[HttpPost]        
    public async Task Progess(MyData mydata)
    {
```

How to get mydata model here from previous page? I want to show UI thats why using `return view` first instead `RedirectToAction`

Comment: look into TempData and TempData.Keep() for this functionality

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://dotnetfiddle.net/c7hAFy

Controller

```
namespace Testy20161006.Controllers
{
    public class MyData
    {
        public string NeoData { get; set; }
    }

    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        [HttpPost]
        //adding generic ActionResult to Task type
        public async Task<ActionResult> Progess(MyData mydata)
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult> AddData(MyData mydata)
        {
            return View("AddDetails", mydata);
        }

        public ActionResult Tut137()
        {
            MyData myData = new MyData { NeoData = "neoData" };
            return View(myData);
        }
```

First Page -Index or Tut137 in my case-

```
@model Testy20161006.Controllers.MyData 
@{
    Layout = null;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Tut137</title>
</head>
<body>
    @using (Html.BeginForm("AddData", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
    {
        @Html.TextBoxFor(r=>r.NeoData);
        <input id="theButton" type="submit" value="Go"  />
    }
</body>
</html>
```

AddDetails.cshtml

```
@model Testy20161006.Controllers.MyData
@{
    Layout = null;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>AddDetails</title>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            var someRootPath = "@Url.Content("~")";
            $.ajax({
                //rename Process to Progess to match call to method called
                url: someRootPath + 'Home/Progess',
                data: $('#AddData').serialize(),
                type: "POST",
            });
        })
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(r => r.NeoData, new { id = "AddData" })
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```